# File manager - jump to file/folder by line number

Tags: vim, filemanager

Is there any file manager that shows a number (similar to line number in vim) for each folder/files in the current directory and you can jump to any folder/file by typing the corresponding number with an action, just like vim?

When dealing with long list of files and folders in a file manager, moving up and down to get to the right file/folder takes time and there must be a better way.

Using commandline would be faster, but still takes time especially if you want to pick a file with long name and lots of other similar filenames in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a file manager that's just like vim, [vifm](https://vifm.info/).  To quote its manpage:

> Vifm  is an ncurses based file manager with vi like keybindings.  If you use vi, vifm gives you complete keyboard control
> over your files without having to learn a new set of commands.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install vifm
```

After the command `:set nu` (which you can set as a default in a `~/.config/vifm/vifmrc` file) it shows line numbers, allowing you to jump to any file with the `G` or `gg` commands just like in `vim`.

Comment: Is there a way to also run command on the files by just entering their number?